# ReactNativeCli init Helloworld project build error with Babel TransformError

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I'm trying to learn React Native development by following instruction:

```
nvm install v4.2.6
nvm alias default v4.2.6
npm install -g react-native-cli
react-native init RNApp
cd RNAPP
```

Then I open iOS app project and compile program. Then I got follow error:

```
...
++ NVM_NPM_PREFIX=/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6
++ nvm_tree_contains_path /Users/user/.nvm /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6
++ '[' -n '' ']'
+ [[ -x /Users/user/.nodenv/bin/nodenv ]]
+ react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev true --bundle-output /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNApp-ckxusxiznabgxxcrqessfpbjyrks/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNApp.app/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RNApp-ckxusxiznabgxxcrqessfpbjyrks/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNApp.app
bundle: Created ReactPackager
uncaught error Error: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-transform-hmr/node_modules/react-proxy/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/lib/index.js: Unknown option: /Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-transform-hmr/node_modules/react-proxy/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/.babelrc.stage
    at Logger.error (/Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:41:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:262:18)
    at OptionManager.addConfig (/Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:221:10)
    at OptionManager.findConfigs (/Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:364:16)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:412:12)
    at File.initOptions (/Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:191:75)
    at new File (/Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:122:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:42:16)
    at transform (/Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/packager/transformer.js:59:24)
TransformError: /Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-transform-hmr/node_modules/react-proxy/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/lib/index.js: [BABEL] /Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-transform-hmr/node_modules/react-proxy/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/lib/index.js: Unknown option: /Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-transform-hmr/node_modules/react-proxy/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/.babelrc.stage
See logs /var/folders/g9/m3cmg0m10cl80xt362wpsld00000gn/T/react-packager.log
    at SocketClient._handleMessage (SocketClient.js:139:23)
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (SocketClient.js:53:42)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at BunserBuf.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at BunserBuf.process (/Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/bser/index.js:289:10)
    at /Users/user/Desktop/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/bser/index.js:244:12
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Is I do something wrong? or just there is something bug in babel for react-native support?

```
➜  RNApp  react-native --version
react-native-cli: 0.1.10
react-native: 0.18.1
```

But it seems that `run-android` is working fine:

```
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
:app:zipalignDebug
:app:assembleDebug
:app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This root cause of the issue is that React Native uses Babel 6, which deprecated the use of the `stage` option on `.babelrc` files, and `react-deep-force-update`, a sub-dependency of React Native, still declares a `.babelrc` file with that option.

This is an issue with any third party modules that still use an older Babel in their own build process and do not clear the configuration files for the npm publish.

I have worked around the issue by adding the following npm run scripts to my `package` json:

```
"scripts": {
  "clean:babelrc": "find ./node_modules -name react-packager -prune -o -name '.babelrc' -print | xargs rm -f",
  "postinstall": "npm run clean:babelrc"
}
```

The script nukes all `.babelrc` files under the `node_modules` directory after every `npm install`, except the one under the `react-packager` directory, which is React Native packager uses to configure its own babel rules.

The issue is being [tracked on React Native GitHub repository](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5393#issuecomment-174319207).

Answer (score 0):

I updated the npm packages.

`react-proxy ==> 1.1.2`

`react-deep-force-update ==> 2.0.1`

You need remove the packages files first in `node_modules`. Then install the new version.

It works for me.